# Capture SVG onresize in Angular2

Tags: angular

My goal is to have an `SVG` canvas in an Angular 2 template that scales with its parent element and calls a redraw method when its size changes.

Using the `onresize` property, I get events as expected but I can't call a method of the Component:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" id="canvas" onresize="console.log('resize')">
</svg>
```

When I use the proper Angular 2 syntax, I can call a method, but the event is never fired:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" id="canvas" (resize)="resize()">
</svg>
```

To test the logic, I changed `(resize)` into `(click)` and then the events are fired when I click on the canvas.

Since this didn't work for me, I tried other ways to attach the `onresize` event.

First I added `#canvas` to the `svg` tag:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" #canvas id="canvas">
</svg>
```

Then I added a `ViewChild` to the Component.

```
  @ViewChild('chart') canvas : ElementRef;
```

I've tried every method as described here: [SVGResize | onresize event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972237(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
function handler() { console.log('SVG resize') }
this.canvas.nativeElement.onresize = handler;
this.canvas.nativeElement.attachEvent("onresize", handler);
this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener("SVGResize", handler);
```

None of them fire any events. The only way so far how I can capture resizes is by setting an event handler at the document level:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  this.draw();
});
```

So whenever the page resizes I can trigger a redraw of the svg. This as a few drawbacks though. First, the `SVG` does not always resize when the document resizes. Second, the SVG could also resize in other situations when the page remains the same size. I can work around those but it isn't that elegant and prone to bugs. It would be much better just handling the resize on the SVG directly.

As soon as I have time I'm going to make a Plunker. I did my tests using Chrome and Firefox.

Why doesn't the `(resize)` output work, and how can I properly handle the canvas resize events?

The only way that I could capture resize events directly on the SVG is by using the `onresize` attribute. Is there a way to call methods of the Component from there?

Comment: You could try `(SVGResize)="resize()"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/SVGResize

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work for me. There is no resize on the element and it seems there also isn't on SVG elements. SVG seems to just emit the same event the document emits. (The Plunker I played with https://plnkr.co/edit/ZGFtvmQHEGZSizvXTgdU?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for making the Plunker. After doing more tests myself, I think it is not possible with an event directly on the SVG. I found [css-element-queries](http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/) that seems a promising alternative. I haven't tried it out yet as I'm caught up in some other things now.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than capturing resize events, I would implement DoCheck ( https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html ) and insert an if test for if the canvas scrollWidth/scrollHeight has changed since the last check. This way you can also check if the size has changed even though the page itself hasn't resized.